# Django Celery shared_task can does not have password suplied

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

When running a task that trys to read or save to django model it is unable to connect due to not having the password

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "db" (172.21.0.2), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

I followed the set up from the celery website: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django

Was there anything I missed or need to change that is undocumented?
I am using config for the backend

```
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq//'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://'

SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'
```

celery.py

```
from celery import Celery

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'irsystem.settings')

app = Celery('irsystem')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django apps.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True, ignore_result=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```